# What causes element height difference in desktop vs iOS

Tags: html, css, ios, webkit, font-size

I was testing a scrolling element and found some strange differences between mobile (iOS) and desktop browsers. If you load [this test website](https://temp-meni-l99.glitch.me) in an iPhone and desktop and inspect the content of the scrolling container I noticed that on iOS the calculated content height of the `<p>` elements is greater than on desktop.

This seems to be a font rendering related thing as the css of the example site is very minimal. I checked all the relevant css props I could think of (like `font-size`, `line-height`, etc) but they all have the same value on both sides.

In the images below `<p>` elements have a total height of 40px (20px margin + 20px content) on iOS and 38px (20px margin + 18px content) on desktop. This makes the total `scrollHeight` of the container element to be 4000px on iOS and 3800px on desktop.

I couldn't find any bug related in webkit bug tracker and I don't have at the moment an android device to test or any kind of table, so I could only test on my iPhone vs desktop. This behaviour can be reproduced in any browser.

#### Things that I tried

1. Other fonts and still could find differences of more than one pixel
2. Embed a google font to test if it had to do with native fonts on mobile vs desktop
3. Instead of 100 paragraphs used only one paragraph but with 100 lines of text
4. Set `-webkit-text-size-adjust` prop to `none`
5. Used some css resets but the difference persisted

Does anybody have a hint on this?

#### Desktop Browser

[image]

#### Mobile Browser

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite new to webdev, but I would try using a specific line height for the paragraphs

Comment: Hi! My question is more related to understanding why this happens, what is causing it. Not really how to fix it.

Comment: The most I could find was to set the -webkit-text-size-adjust to a 100%, and also checking or including the following meta tag <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, height=device-height"/>